Is there any way to add something on PDF that doesn’t invalidate digital singature?
In my asp .net application i need to add contract number on existing PDF with digital signature of end user. I’m using iText7 library.
Is there any way to add something on PDF without invalidate digital signature (e.g annotations)?

do you know what is the main purpose of signature?

I know that when something is signed it shouldn’t be changed , only if you add another signature, but in some libs you have incremental updates so i just asked if there is any way to do that in itext7 because that is the business logic of customer

if it was possible - it would mean that user sign contract with one price, but later you change it with something different, is it not how legal world works

Ye, i understand that and totally agree with that, we asked them to set contract number initially but they refused, thanks anyway!

"We threw the apple. We asked it to fall but it refused." ... sounds like something Douglas Adams could have written.

Which changes are allowed on a signed PDF, depends on the type(s) of signatures added. For details see this answer.

For doing this with iText, you in particular have to make sure you add the changes in an incremental update. You do this by using stamper properties with append mode set.

That still does not ensure the change is also legal in your / client's country. That only means you may be able to not break the original signature.

Indeed, legality is not what can be decided technically. Merely what is allowed or disallowed by technical specifications.
